# RequireJS text plugin - minification of templates

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, requirejs, minify, requirejs-text

I'm using text plugin to import my templates. Now, in production I don't want that there are many XHR requests for templates so I would like to get them in one go. 
My idea was to have build task which would take template and create something like:

```
define("my-template.tpl", function() {
    return '<div>my content</div>'
}
```

and I was able to do this and define statement has been run, but requirejs still does XHR request when I have

```
define("my function", ["my-template.tpl"], function() {
    <body of function here>
});
```

Did someone do any minification of text! plugin templates? Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RequireJS always requests all your modules asynchronously.

If you want one single call, you can build your app using the [optimizer](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html).
You do not need this template wrapper (as you noticed by yourself, it won't change anything). The files required using the `text` plugin will be included in the built file too.